# Rails ActiveRecord doesn't seem to handle null values correctly in the test enviornment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, test-environments

Everything seems to work well in the development and production environments:

```
> script/console
Loading development environment (Rails 2.3.8)
ruby-1.8.7-p302 > Tape.find(:first, :conditions => "deleted_at is not null").deleted_at.nil?
 => false 
ruby-1.8.7-p302 > Tape.find(:first, :conditions => "deleted_at is null").deleted_at.nil?
 => true
```

So why am I getting the exact opposite results in the test environment?

```
> script/console test
Loading test environment (Rails 2.3.8)
ruby-1.8.7-p302 > Tape.find(:first, :conditions => "deleted_at is not null").deleted_at.nil?
 => true
```

Searching for `deleted_at is null` never returns any records in the test environment, even when some calls have `deleted_at = nil` and some have a timestamp there.

Here's a partial readout of the mysql table:

```
mysql> describe tapes;
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
...
| deleted_at      | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Does anyone know what's going on?  Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that the method I was using to create null values in my fixture was incorrect.  It seems that if you want a real null value from a csv fixture is to have that field default to null and just don't include that column in your csv. Hopefully this will help someone else :)

Answer (score 0):

Are your test and production databases both MySQL or is the test database SQLite? Some databases (like SQLite) may treat a null value the same as an empty string, so you want to use `blank?` instead of `nil?`.

Comment: Great thought, but yeah, they're both mysql :/